Ebay API Platform Notifications Implementation and Testing
I'm trying to create an app where users can connect their eBay accounts and view all their active product listings and any changes in price/sold/auctioned etc. I've been using https://github.com/hendt/ebay-api to subscribe to eBay platform notifications.
It all seems to be going well so far since I'm able to connect my sandbox account using valid tokens and I'm also able to set notification preference with success.
a. How do I list and sell items on sandbox to test these notifications? I would like to see those soap webhooks hit my dev server and work from there.
b. Will platform notifications work for items that are listed by the user manually or only for items listed via API on my app? That's not very clear to me from the documation.
Thanks!
